# How to retrieve the current version of a MySQL database management system (DBMS)?

Tags: mysql

What command returns the current version of a MySQL database?

Comment: A surprising number of answers below suggest some variant of `mysql --version`.  This gives the version of the **client** utility, not the server, so it's a bit like trying to find out your version of Apache by loading Firefox and opening the Help->About dialog.

Answer (score 241, accepted):

Many answers suggest to use `mysql --version`. But the `mysql` programm is the client. The server is `mysqld`. So the command should be

```
mysqld --version
```

or

```
mysqld --help
```

That works for me on Debian and Windows.

When connected to a MySQL server with a client you can use

```
select version()
```

or

```
select @@version
```

Comment: mysqld --help is working for me

Answer (score 836):

Try this function -

```
SELECT VERSION();
-> '5.7.22-standard'
```

[VERSION()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_version)

Or for more details use :

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                    |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                                       |
| version                 | 5.0.27-standard                          |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Edition - Standard (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | i686                                     |
| version_compile_os      | pc-linux-gnu                             |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

[MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual (pdf) - Determining Your Current MySQL Version - page 42](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.0-en.pdf)

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/installation-version.html is a 404.

Comment: what if I don't want to run anything related to mysql itself? where is this version information stored?

Comment: @Sajuuk it isn't stored anywhere.  but if you are using some kind of packaging system, that will store the version

Comment: This is instant solution. I got it on first click. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 173):

try

```
mysql --version
```

for instance. Or `dpkg -l 'mysql-server*'`.

Comment: This is the best quick option if you're lazy - you don't even need to log in `:-D` works fine on Centos / RHEL command line as well as Ubuntu.

Comment: @user568458, admittedly, though, it gives you the client's version or the version of local server provided that the one that is installed as a package is running ;)

Comment: The command `mysql --version` is not OS specific. This will work on any Linux distro, Windows and OS X.

Comment: @KolobCanyon, well, unless you don't have it in path :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker Right! Worth mentioning as well that editing the environment variables, including the `$PATH` variable ***IS*** OS specific.

Comment: It says - mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.19-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64). Ok, its maria db and not really mysql, thanks to my xampp installation. I am confused. What does that ver 15.1 mean ?

Comment: @testerjoe2, it's mariadb version, not sure how it corresponds with mysql versions.

Comment: The command that works for the server version will presumably only work if the server is running from a Debian-installed package.

Comment: @mwfearnley, very true.

Answer (score 30):

Use `mysql -V` works fine for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: This gives the version of the `mysql` client utility.  This *might* be a similar version if it's installed on the same system as the server, but if they're on different systems, it could be completely different.

Answer (score 30):

**Mysql Client version** : Please beware this doesn't returns server version, this gives mysql client utility version

```
mysql -version
```

**Mysql server version :** There are many ways to find

1. `SELECT version();`

[image]

2. `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";`

[image]

3. `mysqld --version`

Comment: The `mysql` command needs to be lower case for most non-Windows platforms.  But also, it would be better not to open your answer with the MySQL *client* version, because it's not what's asked for, and could mislead people.

Comment: Idea here is to provide relevant information, not quick answer. Anyway, updated answer based on your suggestion. Thanks!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for listening to my feedback. I would still remove the client info, because it’s not relevant (although it is tangentially related). And at the least I’d recommend opening with the “server version” info. Your warning is helpful though.

Comment: Why a screenshot for what could have been easily copied as text?

Comment: It already has queries in the text format which is easy to copy.

Comment: In contrast to screenshots (speak: pictures) text cannot vanish over time. Being able to copy output text is an advantage for everybody who cannot reproduce it with the same query/command for many reasons. And you could have indented the output (screenshots) as per your numbered list. And point out what's SQL and what's shell.

Answer (score 23):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                    |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                                       |
| version                 | 5.0.27-standard                          |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Edition - Standard (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | i686                                     |
| version_compile_os      | pc-linux-gnu                             |
+-------------------------+------------------------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

[MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual (pdf) - Determining Your Current MySQL Version - page 42](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/refman-5.0-en.pdf)

Answer (score 20):

Go to MySQL workbench and log to the server. There is a field called **Server Status** under **MANAGEMENT**. Click on **Server Status** and find out the **version**.
[image]

Or else go to following location and open cmd -> **C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe**. Then hit the command -> **mysql -V**

[image]

Comment: Note that you get to the 'Management' window by clicking on 'Administration' (rather than 'Schemas') in the tabs at the bottom of the 'Navigator' window on the left.

Answer (score 17):

I found a easy way to get that.

Example: Unix command(this way you don't need 2 commands.),

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";'
```

Sample outputs:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                   |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.5.49                  |
| protocol_version        | 10                      |
| slave_type_conversions  |                         |
| version                 | 5.5.49-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 |
| version_comment         | (Ubuntu)                |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                  |
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu        |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

In above case mysql version is **5.5.49**.

Please find [this useful reference](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tell-version-mysql-unix-linux-command/).

Answer (score 17):

Simply login to the Mysql with

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Then type in this command

```
select @@version;
```

This will give the result as,

```
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.16-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 14):

For *UBUNTU* you can try the following command to check mysql version :

```
mysql --version
```

Comment: This is the same response that @MichaelKrelin answered!

Comment: This will give you the mysql client version, not the server.

Answer (score 12):

MySQL Server version

```
shell> mysqld --version
```

MySQL Client version

```
shell> mysql --version

shell> mysql -V
```

[image]

Comment: These give the version of the `mysql` client utility, which may be completely different from the version the database server is running.

Comment: I see you've updated your answer now to include both, and put the server version first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

`mysqladmin version` OR `mysqladmin -V`

Comment: This will tell mysqladmin client version not to mysql server

Comment: `mysqladmin version` (with appropriate connection details) will give the actual server version, but `mysqladmin -V` gives the version of the `mysqladmin` command-line utility, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 8):

From the console you can try:

```
mysqladmin version -u USER -p PASSWD
```

Answer (score 8):

For Mac,

1. login to mysql server.
2. execute the following command:

   ```
    SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
   ```

Comment: This should work in a MySQL client on any platform.  It's the same solution given in an earlier answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8987742/446106

Comment: This worked for me from Datagrip, and as mentioned earlier, should work from any mysql client, because it is a db query, it is not os dependant so far I understand.

Answer (score 6):

With CLI in one line :

`mysql --user=root --password=pass --host=localhost db_name --execute='select version()';`

or

`mysql -uroot -ppass -hlocalhost db_name -e 'select version()';`

return something like this :

```
+-----------+
| version() |
+-----------+
| 5.6.34    |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also look at the top of the MySQL shell when you first log in.  It actually shows the version right there.

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 67971
Server version: 5.1.73 Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
E:\>mysql -u root -p
Enter password: *******
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1026
Server version: 5.6.34-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> select @@version;
+------------+
| @@version  |
+------------+
| 5.6.34-log |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you please provide some context to your answer.  Though its clear this shows a solution, some explanation as to your approach and why its a good method would be helpful.  Generally just posting code chunks is frowned on in SO.

Comment: I don't think any explanation is needed for why `SELECT @@version;`, which shows the version, would be a good method for showing the version.  The bigger issue IMO is that this answer is a duplicate of earlier answers.

Answer (score 3):

Xampp with Windows users below in the command which worked in the MySQL directory.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In windows ,open Command Prompt and type `MySQL -V` or `MySQL --version`. If you use Linux get terminal and type `MySQL -v`

Comment: quick ! no need to be connected to the database :) thanks

Comment: This is only for the MySQL client, which may be very different from the sever.  Also, the Linux command would need to be lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is important to know which version of MySQL candidate is available to installed by default. here is the little command to check that prior to actually installing.

```
sudo apt-cache policy mysql-server
```

This is more important for any existing project which might be running on old MySQL Versions e.g. 5.7.

A sample output of the above command could be:

> mysql-server:   Installed: (none)     Candidate:
> 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3  Version table:
> 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 500
>
> 500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64
> Packages 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main
> amd64 Packages
> 8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
>
> 500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages

This states that by default by running the following command some flavour of MySQL Server 8 will be installed.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 0):

### Print a Dockerized MariaDB/MySQL Server version:

When I backup a WordPress site- *in this case containerized*- I capture the WordPress version in the filename as well as the DB version that was current at the time of the backup. This ensures that if I ever needed to restore, I wouldn't have a compatibility nightmare figuring out what version DB works with a specified version of the WordPress backup.

So I include the DB server version in the dump name. I loaded the below into a self-populating variable:

```
docker exec -it ContainerIdOfDB mysqld --version | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d'-' -f1
```

This pukes out the current DB version without having to login to retrieve it.

Answer (score -1):

Here two more methods:

**Linux: Mysql view version: from PHP**

From a PHP function, we can see the version used:

```
mysql_get_server_info ([resource $ link_identifier = NULL]): string
```

**Linux: Mysql view version: Package version**

For RedHat / CentOS operating systems:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

For Debian / Ubuntu operating systems:

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql
```

Extracted from: https://www.sysadmit.com/2019/03/linux-mysql-ver-version.html

Answer (score -1):

Only this code works for me

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -V
```

Comment: That returns the version number of the **client**, not of the server