# Derby - LAST_INSERT_ID() doesn't work with JDBC

Tags: derby, spring-jdbc

I can't get last insert id using JdbcTemplate with spring framework, before using last_insert_id() function i have searched for a lot of other ways, but doesn't work with it. 
By the way, my table has

```
private static final String insertResponse =
        "INSERT INTO response (" +
        " idReceiver) " +
        "VALUES (?)";

public static void saveResponse(Response response, User user) {
    dataSource = getDataSource();



    JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

     //"select id from users where username ='"+ user.getUsername +"'";
    // define query arguments
    Object[] params = new Object[] { 1 };
    int[] responseTypes = new int[] { Types.INTEGER };
    int row = template.update(insertResponse, params, responseTypes);
    if (row >0){
    SqlRowSet rowSet = template.queryForRowSet("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id");
    int lastInsertedID=0;
    if (rowSet.next())
        lastInsertedID = rowSet.findColumn("id");
    System.out.println("last insert row is : "+lastInsertedID);
}
```

My response table was create by this command:

```
CREATE TABLE RESPONSE (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY 
   (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
   idReceiver INT NOT NULL
 );
```

When I run this code my JVM says "hey guy, you have this exception:
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS id]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered "" at line 1, column 29."

Comment: If you execute that query directly against the database engine, you have the right result, right?

Comment: Just a guess: can you try with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as ID from dual`?

Comment: @Hakerman it give me the same "Syntax error: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 29."

Comment: @Insac it tell me that dual does not exist

Comment: Sorry,  what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Insac i'm using Mysql

Comment: Which Mysql version?

Comment: @insac I don't know, is maybe a version problem? Can i solve my problem with an "older" solution?

Comment: Not your issue,  but the absence of the dual pseudo table might be.  I tested its existence on mysql 5.7 and it worked.  I was suggesting the dual because I have the impression it is complaining about the absence of the FROM clause

Comment: What if you use `SELECT Id from response where id= LAST_INSERT_ID () `?

Comment: To get your mysql version,  execute `select version() ` (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8987679/5077154).  I'm getting a bit lost: the script you used to create the table doesn't look as valid for mysql (it would have been AUTO_INCREMENT).

Comment: @Insac it doesn't recognize version() or last_isert_id() as a function.. How can i do?
thanks for help

Comment: @Insac it's not mysql, it's apache derby

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/6791645/5077154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone had my same problem, i've solved it, following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665846/identity-from-sql-insert-via-jdbctemplate)..

```
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    template.update(
    new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(java.sql.Connection connection) throws SQLException {
             PreparedStatement ps =
            connection.prepareStatement(insertResponse, new String[] {"id"});
            ps.setInt(1, 1);
            return ps;
          }
        },
        keyHolder);

    System.out.println("last inserted id is "+keyHolder.getKey());
```