# MySQL joins with JSON array data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I am trying to join data between two tables.  But the data is stored using what appears to be JSON array data.  Here is an example:

```
ID  name                types
45  Four O'Clock        {"1":"9","2":"10"}
46  Globe Amaranth      ["8","9"]
```

The second complication is the data is stored in two ways.  With brackets and with braces.  When it uses braces the first item in the key:value is the order and not relevant to my needs.  I only need the second item which is the ID in the related table.

Is there anyway to elegantly perform a join with this data structure in SQL?

Thanks,
-Matt

Comment: What [version of MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8987679/2298301) is it please? If it's 5.7 or higher, then it may be possible to use MySQL's `JSON_EXTRACT` function

Comment: 5.6.35 but I could upgrade to 5.7 if this is easier with that version.