# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1055

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, mysql-error-1055

Changed the database from MySQL to MySQLI and getting the error - A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1055

> Expression #23 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'zipbizzlatestdb.pia.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

```
SELECT *,o.id as id, GROUP_CONCAT(pia.applicantid) as applicants 
FROM `pr_opportunity` as o 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN pr_internal_applicant as pia 
            ON o.id = pia.positionid 
WHERE o.approval_status='Approved' 
and DATE(o.deadline) > DATE(NOW()) 
GROUP BY o.id
```

Filename: /var/www/html/singlecodebase/Feb152017/models/mod_common.php

Line Number: 6999

My model file mod_common is as below:

```
function get_opportunity_list()
{
    $sql = "SELECT *,o.id as id, GROUP_CONCAT(pia.applicantid) as applicants 
            FROM `".$this->myTables['opportunity']."` as o 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN pr_internal_applicant as pia 
            ON o.id = pia.positionid 
            WHERE o.approval_status='Approved' 
            and DATE(o.deadline) > DATE(NOW()) 
            GROUP BY o.id";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        $rows = $query->result();

    }       
    return $rows;
}
```

No clue how to solve this error

Comment: `Changed the database from mysql to mysqli` do you mean you upgraded mysql from 5.6 to 5.7? `mysqli` and `mysql_` are different PHP drivers to interact with `mysql`.

Comment: You might try matching your `(` and `)` brackets in the query

Comment: Remove the `*,` in both queries and it will work. If you do a group by, you either have to use aggregation functions (like GROUP_CONCAT) or put columns you select into the group by clause.

Comment: installed phpmyadmin using one click install which runs Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407  , phpmyadmin vVersion information: 4.5.4.1deb2ubuntu2ersion . Then imported existing db

Comment: You'll need to look at what mysql version you are running, 5.6 and 5.7 handle group bys differently.

Comment: how to check that ?

Comment: @sunshine See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987679/how-to-retrieve-the-current-version-of-a-mysql-database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it occurs in `mysql 5.7` so check this link [https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-how-to-permanently-change-sql-mode-in-mysql/] and follow steps it work fine for me.

Or 
open file

```
vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Add these line at the bottom of the file

```
[mysqld]
# ... other stuff will probably be here
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
```

and save 
then restart mysql

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

> Note not for window os

Comment: did you follow steps

Comment: using which OS?

Comment: @VijaySharma That page is a 404. Best to use the primary source, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html. I also wouldn't change the mode, better to correct the query.

Comment: @chris85 i changed query but its not working for me so i used that it work fine for me , Ya i know that better to correct query rather then changing mode , thanks for your suggestion .

Comment: @vijaySharma, your solutions seems to be a perfect answer, i dont want to rewrite all the queries in the app, thats why

Comment: its ubuntu server

Comment: can i achieve this with phpmyadmin?

Comment: that i don't know

Comment: did you follow step that link i sent you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154236/discussion-between-vijay-sharma-and-sunshine).

Comment: Please come on chat , have been waiting

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Open http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ then click SQL and run this query :

1. `SET sql_mode = '';`
2. `SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));`

Comment: That does the trick for me with laragon mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0):

In reading your SQL, you are asking to return every column (i.e. *), as well as the id a second time (o.id is already retrieved by *), then you are querying for the aggregate function of **GROUP_CONCAT(pia.applicantid)**.  However, your group by Clause only requests to aggregate by (group by) o.id.

SQL doesn't like this because it doesn't know what to do with the other fields in your dataset that you are querying for using *.

I suspect you want to see every applicantid related to o.id in an aggregate fashion.  If so, this is your query and it will work.

```
SELECT o.id as id, GROUP_CONCAT(pia.applicantid) as applicants 
        FROM `".$this->myTables['opportunity']."` as o 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN pr_internal_applicant as pia 
        ON o.id = pia.positionid 
        WHERE o.approval_status='Approved' 
        and DATE(o.deadline) > DATE(NOW()) 
        GROUP BY o.id"
```

If you want to group by other fields, then just add them specifically in your select as well as your group by.  All non-aggregate fields need to be in both the select and the group by.  This is part of the [ANSI Standard](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-99/rules-for-grouping-columns/) and should be true for all SQL flavors.  I believe mysql 5.7 and up is more on this than the prior versions, but I'd follow this as a rule.

Here's some supplemental reading regarding the topic.  Hope this helps.
[MySQL 5.7 Documentation regarding Group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)