# SQL Query using WITH and UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

> Project : Recording in time, out time of persons/
>
> I want to update the out time (having null as a entry ) of latest entry (assuming there are more than one entries having null in out time).
>
> SQL TABLE : ROLLNUMBER, DATE, INTIME, OUTTIME.
>
> While Running the code it is giving syntax error.

```
ps = con.prepareStatement("WITH q AS (SELECT * FROM ENTRY WHERE\
    (ROLLNUMBER =?AND DATE = ? AND OUTTIME IS NULL) OR (ROLLNUMBER = ? AND DATE = ? AND
    OUTTIME IS NULL) ORDER BY INTIME DESC LIMIT 1)
     UPDATE q SET OUTTIME = ?");
```

Comment: CTEs (ie with) is not available until vers 8 mysql. Are you on vers 8?

Comment: whici mysql verson you are using?

Comment: To get your mysql version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987679/how-to-retrieve-the-current-version-of-a-mysql-database

Answer (score 0):

WITH is available in mysql 8

for previous version you coun use a update join with subquery eg:

```
  UPDATE q
  inner join (
  SELECT * FROM ENTRY 
    WHERE (ROLLNUMBER =? AND DATE = ? AND OUTTIME IS NULL) 
    OR (ROLLNUMBER = ? AND DATE = ? AND OUTTIME IS NULL) 
    ORDER BY INTIME DESC LIMIT 1)

    ) t on t.t_key = q.q_key
    SET OUTTIME = ?
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense, because there is no `SET` clause.

Comment: set clause added

Comment: now giving error on inner. And what is  this " t on t.t_key = q.q_key" ?

Comment: " t on t.t_key = q.q_key" is the suggestion fo yor table column relation between the two table  ..you must assign to the t_key and q_key the proper column name ...

Comment: What is the query without use of join

Comment: explain better your last comment  .. is not clear to me ..(answer updated .. set clause in wrong position)

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MySQL, the right syntax would be:

```
UPDATE entry
    SET OUTTIME = ?
    WHERE (ROLLNUMBER = ? AND DATE = ? AND OUTTIME IS NULL) OR
          (ROLLNUMBER = ? AND DATE = ? AND OUTTIME IS NULL)
    ORDER BY INTIME DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

To be honest, this looks simpler than the version using the CTE.  Do note that the order of the parameters has changed a bit.

Comment: not working. no table name in your query. TABLE NAME = ENTRY.

Comment: Giving error on order by. And don't know the sql version. What is the method to find that?