# Stored procedure works in localhost but not in server

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This bunch of codes work greatly on localhost(homestead virtual machine and mysql). Actually, the stored procedure code was written in mysql workbench but when I migrate the code to the online version, it does not work and I don't see any error it output. This is the code below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`homestead`@`%` PROCEDURE `catalog_get_products_on_catalog`(
IN inShortProductDescriptionLength INT,
IN inProductsPerPage INT, IN inStartItem INT)
BEGIN
PREPARE statement FROM
"SELECT p.id, p.name,
IF(LENGTH(p.description) <= ?,
p.description,
CONCAT(LEFT(p.description, ?),
'...')) AS description,
p.price, p.discounted_price, i.name AS img_name
FROM products p, imgs i
WHERE display = 1 OR display = 3
AND p.id = i.product_id
ORDER BY display DESC
LIMIT ?, ?";
SET @p1 = inShortProductDescriptionLength;
SET @p2 = inShortProductDescriptionLength;
SET @p3 = inStartItem;
SET @p4 = inProductsPerPage;
EXECUTE statement USING @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What might be the possible problem? Is it because it was created with mysql workbench and I created it with phpmyadmin in the cpanel? And how do I fix it

Comment: add an error handler and see if it thriws an erro https://stackoverflow.com/a/7765950/5193536  Do you havethe same version of mysql on both servers

Comment: @nbk That i dont know if I have the same version of mysql server

Comment: try this on both https://stackoverflow.com/a/55045330/5193536

Comment: @nbk where will I run that query? phpmyadmin?

Comment: workbench or phpmyadmin, every client will do

Comment: @nbk the sever version is 5.7.27-cll-lve while the local is 5.7.22-0ubuntu18.04.1. I dont really think that is much of a different

Comment: yes, it doesn't matter, but you had to check. try error handling

Comment: @nbk you mean php tryand catch? Or does mysql has its own version

Comment: see my first link in the first comment

Comment: Why do you use a prepared statement? You can pass the parameters directly in the query.

Comment: Does `homestead`@`%` definer exists in your Server?

Comment: @james no. I use adans@localhost but I just copied the one on localhost  and paste it here

Comment: @shadow are you saying it might be a possible reason for not working

Comment: He said when you have a direct query then why using a complex prepared query unless needed.

Comment: Try this code of block to capture warnings/ errors *declare continue handler for sqlwarning, not found, sqlexception
begin
declare errno int;
declare state char(7);
declare msg text;

get stacked diagnostics condition 1
errno = mysql_errno,state= returned_sqlstate, msg= message_text;
select errno,state,msg;
end;* place this block in the beginning next to `BEGIN` .... my_code ....prepare statement....then share the error here

Comment: a) what does "not working" mean exactly? b) have you verified that the procedure has been created? (in phpmyadmin, it should be listed in the procedure tab/the database tree on the left side) c) a common problem on linux systems is case sensitivity of table names - can you check if your tables names are lowercase? (e.g. "products" and not "Products")

Comment: @solarflare the stored procedure has been. I will check the table names for case sensitivity and at the end try what james wrote